editing answers?
Is editing answers to reflect the question frowned upon?
I can see answers that answer a question and add extra, irrelevant information My attempts to tighten a answer are reverted because they "deface the answer" but clearly no way is possible to engage in the reverter
Similarly, editing question to match an accepted answer seems impossible

I saw your edit attempts. I disagree with your assessment of irrelevant information. I do consider your edit being contrary to what the original author wanted to convey. It is better to engage with comments and voting to clarify such things. When you remove half the text, it'll not pass the review. Similar for questions: don't add something that wasn't asked; most authors will rollback anyway.

It is upto the answer owner to give more information which is not relevant to the question but as long as some part of that answer answers the questions, it is accepted. If you remove that portion,  you are changing the author intent and they will rollback the changes. The posts will not only help the OP but to the future readers stumbling on the post and will be helped with the information.

Same goes with questions. The OP can ask the exact question or choose certain phrases and you cannot alter them based on the answer received as you will be altering OP's intent.

Thanks - understood, so why do we allow edits to other people's work at all, if we cannot be sure of their intent?

You need to get 50 rep - free commenting to be able to consult serious edits. A lot is possible, but, well, you're completely new here, so don't do anything controversial.

I edited this: "but clearly no way is possible to engage in the reverter" to this  "but there is no clear way to engage the reverter." as what you wrote did not make sense.

You might add a link to the post in question.

Reverted as intent changed.

Please edit your post to meet the quality standards of the site. Beyond poor punctuation and spelling, as I explained in a previous comment there is a statement that does not make sense. My edits were an attempt to amend that.

And so the inconsistency continues. I have suggested edits to the answer at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/185086/in-the-fischer-esterification-mechanism-what-happens-to-the-second-alcohol-grou/185105#185105 to tidy the English but these are also promotional and declined automatically


Is editing answers to reflect the question frowned upon?

Generally speaking, yes. Edits should preserve the intent of the author, as explained here:

When should I edit posts?
Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so.
Some common reasons to edit a post are:

To fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
To include additional information only found in comments, so that all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
To add related resources or hyperlinks

Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged; try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

Editing someone else's post is not generally ok except to improve spelling/grammar/formating (punctuation, textbreaks, mathjax/mhchem), and more rarely to include information revealed in comments by interaction with the OP. Intent should be evident from reading a question or answer. If unsure about what is intended then you should post a comment to seek clarification. Sometimes it is ok to rewrite text that is clearly confused but where the intent is obvious.

Similarly, editing question to match an accepted answer seems impossible

Again, this goes against the site's philosophy. The OP has priority.
You are always welcome to post your own answer or a new question.
Note also that users can be expected to inform themselves about how the site works, although there is a learning curve. One answer you posted falls into the domain of "links as answers", which are routinely booted into comments, no questions asked (it happens automatically if unaccompanied by text). I accelerated what would have been the expected outcome. Links are generally not considered sufficient as an answer on this site. Answers should be standalone. Also, links can die.

Thanks Buck, ironic then that you have moved some of my answers without commenting or checking with me?

@jenny.essex Maybe. Users can be expected to inform themselves about how the site works, although there is a learning curve. The answer you posted falls into the domain of "links as answers", which are routinely booted into comments, no questions asked (it happens automatically if unaccompanied by text). I accelerated what would have been the expected outcome. In any case, now you know, and hopefully no hard feelings.

Links are generally not considered sufficient as an answer on this site. Answers should be standalone. Also, links can die.
